# Listbox foreach loop

Tags: powershell

Problem:  When using the following code in Sapien Powershell Studio computer names are returned correctly but computer descriptions are returned as one line.  In other words all computer descriptions are not separated but appear as one long list.

If Out-String is removed I am only returned one computer description.

I have used basically the same code before when outputting to a textbox and have had no issue.

```
$searchbutton_Click={
#TODO: Place custom script here

$computerlist.Items.clear()

$username = "*" + $searchbox.text + "*"

$computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter { Description -like $username } -
Properties description | select -expand name

foreach ($computer in $computers)
{
    $compdescription = (Get-ADComputer -Filter { Description -like $username 
    } -Properties description).description | out-string

    $results = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.listviewitem($computer)

    $results.subitems.add($compdescription)

    $computerlist.Items.Add($results)



}

}
```

Comment: Only get the computer object once, and this goes twice as fast: `Get-ADComputer -Filter { Description -like $username } -Properties description | ForEach{$Results = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.listviewitem($_.Name);$results.subitems.add($_.Description);$computerlist.Items.Add($results)}` That could replace everything past your `$username =` line, excluding the final closing `}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things are wrong.

(1) You are using twice the same query for Get-ADComputer. Why? I presume second one should be something like below. If not, you are storing into $compdescription value of description for all computers.

```
(Get-ADComputer -Filter { name -like $computer 
    } -Properties description).description
```

(2) About your question on returning one big string with all descriptions. From documentation:

> By default, Out-String accumulates the strings and returns them as a
>   single string, but you can use the stream parameter to direct
>   Out-String to return one string at a time.

See more at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-string)

Comment: Awesome!  Your suggestion on changing the Get-ADComputer query fixed everything.  Thank you!

Comment: I added comment as above for easier understanding. Fully proper way would be to use only one AD query. Modify code as this:

`$computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter { Description -like $username } -
Properties description

foreach ($computer in ($computers.name))
{
    $compdescription = $computer.description | out-string`

You are storing information about all computers in object array, not string array. This information includes both name and description. Then you manipulate that array to get required information.